# Grails .findAll() is returning the same database row many times over, what could cause this?

Tags: oracle, rest, grails, groovy, hql

I have a rather mundane Oracle table with seven rows. Each row has different values, there is a unique key that keeps most of the columns from having similar data.

In a Grails controller I am running the following code:

```
else if (request.method == "GET" && params.term) {
  def a = WaiverExemption.findAll("from WaiverExemption as e where e.exemptionTermCode.id = ?", [parseLong(params.term)]) as JSON
  a.render(response)
  return false
}
```

The browser is making the correct request to this. It passes in a valid term, and in the IntelliJ debugger I can see that the term is correct. Until sometime last week, this particular snippet of code was working correctly... my troubles were related to getting Backbone and jQuery to make use of the json data returned.

Now, instead of returning the 7 rows of data that I expect, it returns the same row 7 times.  This row happens to be the first row returned in the Oracle client (though since I wasn't using any order by, technically speaking, it's not the first row at all... no guarantee of order and all that).

So far I've done multiple "grails clean" on it. I have of course stopped and restarted the application multiple times, and I've tried this both in debug and regular execution.

The only change to this code was the addition of another column in the domain class. But the timing doesn't correspond well to when this started screwing up. The new column was actually Oracle's ROWID, which I didn't expect to work but did make another problem easier to solve. Removing that doesn't revert this to working, however.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

[edit] Debug results after fixing the config.groovy as requested:

```
2012-09-17 10:26:02,675 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - select waiverexem0_.EXEMPTION_TERM_CODE as EXEMPTION1_26_, waiverexem0_.exemption_activity_date as exemption2_26_, waiverexem0_.exemption_classification as exemption3_26_, waiverexem0_.exemption_code as exemption4_26_, waiverexem0_.exemption_pay_type as exemption5_26_, waiverexem0_.exemption_priority as exemption6_26_, waiverexem0_.ROWID as ROWID7_26_, waiverexem0_.exemption_term_code as exemption1_26_, waiverexem0_.exemption_user_id as exemption8_26_ from TT_ST_GRADUATE_EXEMPTION waiverexem0_ where waiverexem0_.exemption_term_code=?
```

Comment: Does `a` contain the same item 7 times, or is it the client-side code that is rendering the same thing 7 times despite the json containing 7 different things?  This sounds like a JS issue...

Comment: No. If I go directly to the json/rest url and manually create the correct URL, it's the same 7 records. This is a Grails thing, not a Backbone thing. I spent 3 hours on it before I realized that, assumed it had to be javascript being screwy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen this specific problem before, but were I to encounter it I would debug it like so:

- Turn on Hibernate SQL debugging so I can see the SQL that Grails is throwing at Oracle. In the Config.groovy log4j configuration, add 'org.hibernate.SQL' to the debug section. Then copy-paste this SQL from the IntelliJ console into a Oracle connected SQL client and see what results it returns.
- Before running the query in the controller do a `println params.term`
- println the results of findAll before rendering the response.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I've run it, the query it produces is ugly, but boring. The where clause is correct, and returns all 7 rows correctly.  I'll edit that into the question.

Comment: What does this output? println WaiverExemption.findAll("from WaiverExemption as e where e.exemptionTermCode.id = ?", [parseLong(params.term)])

Comment: Would also be good to see the mapping for WaiverExemption, I'm seeing exemption_term_code come back twice in the SQL projection.

Comment: It was in the mapping. It stopped happening as soon as I disabled rowid, though I think there may have been a syntax error in there that I somehow fixed without noticing. Why it wasn't throwing some sort of error, still don't know.